# How can I call a method to a component prop - VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I'm trying to format a prop with a method that I've created. Is it possible?

I'm looking for something like this:

My component:

```
props:{
      title: String,
      min: String,
      formatedDate: this.formateDate(formatedDate)
}
```

Where I call this component the date is started as a empty string, but I change that value by a date-picker.

Is it possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a computed property based on  that prop which uses the method:

```
props:{
      title: String,
      min: String,
      date: String
},

computed:{
    formatedDate(){
       return this.formateDate(this.date)
    }
}
```

Comment: But my date will start as a empty string and I'll update it based on events. I forgot to mention that, I think computed only renders automatically when the page renders, right? I'm new to vue

Comment: computed property changes every time the prop changes not only in start